# Link to Another Report and Send Parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 reports and I'd like to create a link on one report that sends parameters to another report that requires them. How can I create this link? Note: I can access the "inner" report via a URL.

Comment: So you have report A that contains a Sub report to B? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I have a Report A that contains a table of information. In that table, I want items in the table to link to Report B that pass particular data as parameters to Report B.

Comment: You can send the parameters to a sub report by selecting the sub report and left click for options. You will see parameters as a selectable option. You can not share datasets between reports but you can send parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can launch the second report by clicking on a cell in the table. To do this right click on the cell and select Text Box Properties. In the properties form go down to the Action tab, and in there, check **Go to report** option, specify the second report and then click the add button. This allows you to pass through one or more parameters to the second report.

If you have to provide a URL for the sub report then you will have to build the URL yourself using an expression for the URL. Instead of checking **Go to report** you would check **Go to url**.

The following link shows how to pass parameters in URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155391.aspx